# Check the render method of `App`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

App.js

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {Typeahead, Control} from 'react-typeahead';
import {FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      multiple: false
    }
}

    render() {
      const {multiple} = this.state;
      return (

    <Fragment>
      <Typeahead
        labelKey="name"
        multiple={multiple}
        options={[
        'Waylon Dalton',
        'Justine Henderson',
        'Abdullah Lang',
        'Marcus Cruz',
        'Thalia Cobb',
        'Mathias Little',
        'Eddie Randolph',
        'Angela Walker',
        'Lia Shelton',
        'Hadassah Hartman',
        'Joanna Shaffer',
        'Jonathon Sheppard'
      ]}
        placeholder="Choose a state..."
      />
      <FormGroup>
        <Control
          checked={multiple}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({multiple: e.target.checked})}
          type="checkbox">
          Multi-Select
        </Control>
      </FormGroup>
    </Fragment>
       )
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I created this project using CRA. This error states that there is something wrong in my import/export but i don't find anything wrong in my import/export of both the files, error is focusing on App.js render function and also render of index.js file. I also checked here but it didn't work for me, can someone help me.

Comment: i think you need to define at least empty div inside return (
       ) in APP

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam tried that it didn't work.

Comment: okay then keep the div in the render and try removing the react-typeahead and react-bootstrap this should definatly work

Comment: btw are you using react-router-dom and which version are u using

Comment: No i'm not using react-router-dom, 16.4. Okay so  that worked but i want to make use of react-typeahead and bootstrap APIs

Comment: my guess it is issue of react-typeahead and not react bootstrap

Comment: Try installing the dependencies again for me it works after adding a div in render of App.js

Comment: Yeah i believe so, I have edited the render method.

Comment: check here :https://codesandbox.io/s/m7qjxno53j

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your App import/export is ok.

I think you mixed up the `Fragment` import (it's part of React) and the `Control` import:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {Typeahead} from 'react-typeahead';
import {FormGroup, FormControl as Control} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: There is already code inside return but still i tried what you mentioned, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the actual render method? Maybe some component you are rendering within are `undefined`

Comment: I'm not familiar with react-typeahead, but i think you want to use `import {Fragment} from 'react'`

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: Sorry, based upon the initial question, this was the answer :)

Comment: No Control is not a part of typeahead.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. In my case it was me using the wrong HOCs from MobX, namely `observable` instead of `observer`.

If you have made the same mistake you can fix it by switching

```js
export default observable(MyReactComponent);
```

to

```js
export default observer(MyReactComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure if this will help, but this solved it for me.

First code to bring the same error

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Link} from 'react-dom';***
import './App.css';
```

Then I realized that it's actually supposed to be

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';***
import './App.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check import statements

It may be likely that your import statements are not importing from the correct files. Make sure that they are all correct.

example:

```
import { Link } from "react"; // oops! hard to see, but that's the wrong file.
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; // that's better
```

#### Check spelling of components

```
// what's wrong with this?
const pageOne = () => {
  return (<Link to="/pagetwo"> pagetwo </Link>); // oops! spelling of the component is wrong!
};

const pageTwo = () => {
  return (<Link to="/"> pageone </Link>);
};
```

They're not going to work because the spelling of the components are not right. It's easy to spot when you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Give your options element a key attribute having a unique id/key like...

```
<options key={value}>
some dummy options here
<options/>
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue resides here:

```
import {Typeahead, Fragment, Control } from 'react-typeahead';
```

The `Typeahead` import is okay but I think `Fragment` and `Control` are the source of your error. Can upi please try to remove them and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes i removed Fragment and found it is an export of  react package but unable to figure out Control export.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: @XDX i think it is a part of react-redux-form

Comment: @Weedoze can you tell why this is so that next time i don't do it ,
i have checked documentation of react-typeahead and there is no import for Fragement and Control and this is the issue

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam I understand your point of view but I think that it is a comment because you are using words like "I think the issue ...", "Please try to remove...". Now if he removes it and it still doesn't work ? You can ask OP to try think in comment to add more information to the question and when it is clearer you can post it as an answer because your 100% sure it will fix the problem. This is only my opinion and I am not an admin :)